# Check if string array elements have different values

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list

What is the most elegant way to check if elements of a string array (list) have different values.

E.g.

```
string[] myArray = { "one", "one", "two"};
```

Output:

> false

E.g.

```
string[] myArray = { "one", "two", "three" };
```

Output:

> true

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
myArray.Distinct().Count() == myArray.Length
```

Comment: @Habib it compares the number of unique items with the number of items, which seems to answer the question.

Answer (score 5):

How about

```
string[] myArray = { "one", "two", "three" };

bool result = myArray.Length == myArray.Distinct().Count();
```

`.Distinct()` removes dupicate values from a List - so you just have to compare the number of items in the  initial array and the distinct one.

Answer (score 1):

A different method without using Linq:

```
var test = new HashSet<string>();
foreach (var str in myArray)
{
    if (test.Contains(str)) return false;
    test.Add(str);
}
return true;
```

Might perform better with some data sets.

Answer (score 1):

Although not very elegant, it's the first thing that came to my mind.

```
string[] myArray = { "one", "one", "three" };

bool result = myArray.Length == new HashSet<string>(myArray).Count;
```

I'm kind of late... And I wish I didn't have to specify the `<string>` part...

Comment: I guess you mean something like `myArray.ToHashSet()`. It's strange that MS didn't add such standard extension method.